# Angular/TypeScript create object with dynamic key

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an object "config" and an id "id",
I would like to create an array of objects that has the following structure:

```
[
  "id" : {
          "config1: ...
          "config2: ...
          "config3: ...

         }
  "id2" : {
          "config1: ...
          "config2: ...
          "config3: ...

         }

]
```

I tried the following code:

```
garage.push( {this.id : this.config });
```

but it causes compiling errors such as:

```
ERROR in component.ts (168,51): An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name in strict mode.
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: How is `garage` declared? What is its type?

Comment: let garage = [];

Comment: _"Compiling errors"_? Can add these to your question?

Comment: added @evolutionxbox

Comment: Are you not also getting a `SyntaxError`?

Comment: sorry have you tried something lke:garage.push( {'id' : this.config });

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may try below,

```
let _temp = {};
_temp[this.id] = this.config;
garage.push(_temp);
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Solves the syntax problems, but OP will still struggle with their "compile" error.